# Footer appears in the middle of content sometimes in my wordpress website. how to fix it?

Tags: wordpress

the footer of my wordpress website appears in the middle of contents. as you can see in the image below. it doesn't happen everytime i load any page. It is likely to happen when when the page have more words and images.

I think it's not theme related issue, because i faced the same issue in another theme in this same website. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl5aD.png

As a newbie, i could not do anything yet to fix it.